# ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Starter Application in Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to get **ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Starter Application** to show-up in the **Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition's** project dialog?

I have tried various online examples unsuccessfully...

**This Is What I WANT:**
[image]

**This Is What I HAVE/KEEP GETTING:**
Even after installing the various online examples...

[image]

Comment: maybe install project template?

Comment: I did...but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short-answer is...as of this date...you cant (yet).

However, the steps described in the [Building Web Apps Powered by Angular 2.x using Visual Studio 2017](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103) video takes you through the set of console commands needed to get setup.